# How do I fix "'ag-grid-angular' is not a known element" problem?

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am having an issue with my angular code where my ag-grid tags aren't being recognised, and neither are my columnDefs and rowData. I have looked up the issues and imported what I needed to but the problem still persists. I had the code working for a short time, then I generated another component (which is where I started to move the MatExpansionPanel code into) and that's when I started getting the errors. I have since removed this component and put the code back to how it was when it worked, but I still get errors.

search.component.html:

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="true">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>Search</mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  <ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
  </ag-grid-angular>

</mat-expansion-panel>
```

search.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MOVIES } from '../movies';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-popular',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent {

  rowData = MOVIES;

  columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {field: 'title'},
    {field: 'description', resizable: true},
    {field: 'release_year'},
    {field: 'genre', resizable: true},
    {field: 'availability', resizable: true},
    {field: 'runtime'},
    {field: 'rating'},
  ];
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LatestComponent } from './latest/latest.component';
import { PopularComponent } from './popular/popular.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LatestComponent,
    PopularComponent,
    SearchComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormControl,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

MOVIES, used in rowData, is an exported array of type movie (created with interface).

***EDIT***
I have found that this isn't an issue to do with ag-grid as I am receiving an error for all angular components.

Comment: Which version of ag grid are you using and is the node module folder up to date?
Here is a small working example inspired by your code. The only different is not using the withComponents method as it is not needed anymore.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-k9klch?file=src/app/app.component.ts. ... and well the movies data was not provide, so please sorry the worst example set ever

Comment: I am working on V29.2.0, this is on node_modules/ag-grid-communty/ag-grid-community.min.js. I couldn't find the version on ag-grid-angular. I have reinstalled ag-grid to see if I am missing anything but that didn't work.  Thank you very much for making the example code, I cannot see the ag-grid unfortunately.

Comment: I updated the example, unfortunately your style was not working probably in this pure example project. I replaced the height: 100% with height: 250px

Answer (score 1):

Registering the `AG Grid` components like this:

```
AgGridModule.withComponents([])
```

is no longer necessary (or supported).

Just importing `AgGridModule` in your `app.module.ts` is enough:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LatestComponent,
    PopularComponent,
    SearchComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    AgGridModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormControl,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/angular-compatibility/#migration-to-ag-grid-v28